# Latest forums posts by date

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework, lambda

I have this Lambda statement:

```
TPGForumPost.Select(v => v).OrderByDescending(d => d.dateCreated)
```

I need to figure out how to limit this to 5 of the latest posts.

Comment: `TPGForumPost.OrderByDescending(d => d.dateCreated).Take(5)` would be enough, you don't need `Select`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get the last 5 posts:

```
TPGForumPost.Select(v => v).OrderByDescending(d => d.dateCreated).Take(5);
```

The second part requires more info, and maybe should be a separate question since it's completely unrelated.

Answer (score 2):

You want to use the [Take extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb503062%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

`TPGForumPost.Select(v => v).OrderByDescending(d => d.dateCreated).Take(5);`